# Can you play Pokémon Go on Oneplus 2 with CM13?

Tags: cyanogenmod, gps, oneplus-two, pokemon-go

It worked in Oxygen OS but now lagging.  Fig. 1 No appearance of poketops and pokemons, loading sign at the left top corner

[image]

System: CM13 with GApps installed
Phone: Oneplus 2

Comment: You absolutely should be - so far I haven't had issues with proprietary games on CyanogenMod 12 & 13 and I don't even have Google Play Services installed (I download apps by other means). Generally OnePlus and Nexus phones are most compatible with third-party ROMs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oneplus 2 and Pokemon Go do not work well together as of August 2016 if GPS is in the high accuracy mode.

If you enable GPS only mode and restart then Pokemon works normally.

Comment: Well, you should try using GPS only especially if you don't have GApps installed.

Comment: @user598527 I have GApps installed.  I've posted a followup question here http://android.stackexchange.com/q/155555/9897

Comment: I've cleaned up the comments here and edited the answer -- please note that Community Wiki is intended for wiki-style answers, not self-answers.