# How to Play Pokémon Go in High Accuracy GPS -mode with Oneplus 2 of CM13?

Tags: cyanogenmod, gps, oneplus-two, pokemon-go

It is possible to play Pokémon Go in *GPS only* mode in Oneplus 2 of CM13 as described in the thread [Can you play Pokémon Go on Oneplus 2 with CM13?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/155475/9897) However, the application does not work in the high accuracy mode with the device. I would like to understand which technology Wifi/Bluetooth/... is disturbing the game and GPS, in order to understand how to play the game in the high accuracy mode. 
I have not seen the same problem with Samsung Galaxy Phones of CM13. 
Fig. 1 Output in High Accuracy Mode

[image]

Test configurations tested in High Accuracy Mode

1. Fresh installation of the OS - no difference
2. Clean memory before starting Pokemon or not - no difference
3. Bluetooth on and off - no difference
4. Power saving mode on and off - no difference
5. Google Wear installed but no devices connected to the application; tested also as uninstalled - no difference
6. All internet gadgets (Pebble, Xiaomi Mi Band 2) disconnected from the phone - no difference
7. Using own local wifi network or not - no difference
8. ...

System: CM13
Phone: Oneplus 2
Pokémon Go: 0.33.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Pokemon's server side problem. You cannot do anything here but wait that the company improves. Now, the situation is better.